# ~./zshrc : command not found: $

Tags: python, django, macos, unix, zsh

I'm currently going through Django tutorials on ProjectDjango.com.

However I'm stuck on the very first bit!

I'm told to enter the following into the command line:

```
$ python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
```

When I do this in the main CLI I get:

```
~ $ python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
zsh: command not found: $
```

When I try it in the python terminal I get:

```
>~ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>$ python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    $ python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My research into this so far has led me to believe it could be a problem with my `./zshrc` file, but this is way beyond my understanding of Macs, as a friend installed ohmyzsh for me.

When I type `echo $PATH` in the CLI I get:

```
/Users/davidmellor/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/davidmellor/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/davidmellor/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/davidmellor/anaconda3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/davidmellor/anaconda3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/davidmellor/anaconda3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`
```

Which just seems messy to me!

Answer (score 2):

### `$` marks your prompt, it is not meant to be copied.

People include it with their code because it easily distinguishes that you are supposed to put in console.

For example, `$` means unix shell (usually *bash*), `#` means root console, `>>>` means Python console.

Answer (score 0):

As **pacholik** said, `$` should not be included:

`$ python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"`

should be:

`python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"`

Comment: Thank you sainoba, as above, I get "No module named Django"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to remove the character `$` and only executing `python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())`? The character `$` usually indicates that is a bash command, but you don't need to execute it.

Also, You can open the python console and execute `import django; print(django.get_version())` and get the same result.

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo - I tried this, but I get "No module named Django", but then when I try typing django-admin I get a list of sub commands, so I know it's installed.